# 3 columnas en ESC-POS PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy tratando de imprimir un ticket de venta usando el script Mike42 ESC-POS.
Hasta el momento, solo puedo imprimir 2 columnas, pero el realidad necesito 3. 
La idea es que aparezca la cantidad, el producto y la cantidad.
Esta demas decir, que la informacion viene de mysql usando php.

Alguien tiene alguna idea o me oriente a como poder realizar esto?

Comment: Agrega un link al script que mencionas para poder dar mayor información a tu consulta...

Comment: @NBPalomino este es el autor https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php

Comment: lo lograste? tengo el mismo problema

Comment: @arglez35 si. edito mi pregunta para poner como lo logre. saludos y espero te sirva.

Answer (score 1):

Logre encontrar la solucion al problema.
Espero que pueda servirle a otros.

Saludos.

```
function normaliza ($cadena){
$originales = 'ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûýýþÿŔŕ';
$modificadas = 'aaaaaaaceeeeiiiidnoooooouuuuybsaaaaaaaceeeeiiiidnoooooouuuyybyRr';
$cadena = utf8_decode($cadena);
$cadena = strtr($cadena, utf8_decode($originales), $modificadas);

return utf8_encode($cadena);
}

require __DIR__ . '\autoload.php';

use Mike42\Escpos\Printer;
use Mike42\Escpos\EscposImage;
use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\WindowsPrintConnector;

$logo = EscposImage::load("bt.jpg", false);

$date = date('d-m-Y H:i:s');

// Enter the share name for your USB printer here
$connector = new WindowsPrintConnector("smb://127.0.0.1/XP-801");

$printer = new Printer($connector);

$printer -> setJustification(Printer::JUSTIFY_CENTER);
$printer -> bitImage($logo);
$printer -> feed();

$consulta = "SELECT
usuarios.nombre,
usuarios.apellido,
ubicacion.nombre AS ubicacion

FROM ventas

INNER JOIN usuarios ON usuarios.id = ventas.usuario
INNER JOIN ubicacion ON ubicacion.id = ventas.ubicacion

WHERE ventas.mesa = '$id_mesa' AND ventas.estado = 'S' AND ventas.salon = 1 ";

$resultado = $conexion->query($consulta);
if ($resultado->num_rows > 0){
while ($qry = $resultado->fetch_array()){
    $nombre = $qry['nombre'];
    $apellido = $qry['apellido'];
    $ubicacion = $qry['ubicacion'];
}
}

/* Name of shop */
$printer -> selectPrintMode(Printer::MODE_DOUBLE_WIDTH);
$printer -> setTextSize(1, 1);
$printer -> text("DETALLE CONSUMO POR CLIENTE MESA $id_mesa.\n");
$printer -> text("$ubicacion\n");
$printer -> selectPrintMode();
$printer -> text("ATENDIDO POR: ".strtoupper($nombre)." 
".strtoupper($apellido)."\n");
$printer -> feed();

/* Title of receipt */
$printer -> setEmphasis(true);
$printer -> text("$date\n");
$printer -> setEmphasis(false);
$printer -> feed();

/* Items */
$printer -> setJustification(Printer::JUSTIFY_LEFT);
$printer -> setEmphasis(false);
$printer -> text("-----------------------------------------------");

foreach ($clientes AS $key){
$printer -> feed();
$printer -> text(new item(strtoupper($key)));

foreach ($prod AS $key2){

    $consulta = "SELECT

    productos.nombre,
    ventas.valor,
    ventas.cantidad,
    ventas.cliente

    FROM ventas

    INNER JOIN productos ON productos.id = ventas.producto

    WHERE ventas.id_cl = 1 AND ventas.mesa = '$id_mesa' AND ventas.salon = 1 AND ventas.estado = 'S' AND productos.id = '$key2' AND ventas.cliente = '$key'";

    $resultado = $conexion->query($consulta);
    if ($resultado->num_rows > 0){
        while ($qry = $resultado->fetch_array()){

            $printer -> text(new item($qry["cantidad"]. " X " .normaliza(strtoupper($qry['nombre'])),"$".number_format($qry['valor'], 0,',','.')));

        }
    }

}

$consulta = "SELECT

SUM(ventas.valor) AS total,
ROUND(SUM(ventas.valor))+SUM((ventas.valor * 0.1)) AS totalv

FROM ventas

WHERE ventas.id_cl = 1 AND ventas.mesa = '$id_mesa' AND ventas.salon = 1 AND ventas.estado = 'S' AND ventas.cliente = '$key'";

$resultado = $conexion->query($consulta);
if ($resultado->num_rows > 0){
    while ($qry = $resultado->fetch_array()){
        $total_cl = $qry['total'];

        $printer -> feed();
        $printer -> text(new item("SUBTOTAL: $".number_format($qry['total'], 0,',','.')));
        $printer -> text(new item("PROPINA SUGERIDA: $".number_format($qry['total'] * 0.1, 0,',','.')));
        $printer -> text(new item("TOTAL: $".number_format($qry['totalv'], 0,',','.')));
        $printer -> text("-----------------------------------------------");

    }
}
}

$consulta = "SELECT

SUM(ventas.valor) AS valor_mesa,
ROUND(SUM(ventas.valor) * 0.1) AS propina_mesa,
ROUND(SUM(ventas.valor)+SUM(ventas.valor * 0.1)) AS total_mesa,
usuarios.nombre,
usuarios.apellido

FROM ventas

INNER JOIN usuarios ON usuarios.id = ventas.usuario

WHERE ventas.mesa = '$id_mesa' AND ventas.estado = 'S' AND ventas.salon = 1 ";

$resultado = $conexion->query($consulta);
if ($resultado->num_rows > 0){
//$totalx = $qry['total'];
while ($qry = $resultado->fetch_array()){
    $valor_mesa = $qry["valor_mesa"];
    $propina_mesa = $qry["propina_mesa"];
    $total_mesa = $qry["total_mesa"];
    $nombre = $qry['nombre'];
    $apellido = $qry['apellido'];
}
}

$total_sub = number_format($valor_mesa, 0,',','.');
$total_prop = number_format($propina_mesa, 0,',','.');
$total_tot = number_format($total_mesa, 0,',','.');

$subtotal = new item('SUBTOTAL', "$".$total_sub);
$tax = new item('PROPINA SUGERIDA', "$".$total_prop);

$total = new item('TOTAL', "$".$total_tot, true);

$printer -> feed();
$printer -> setEmphasis(true);
$printer -> text($subtotal);
$printer -> setEmphasis(false);
$printer -> feed();


/* Tax and total */
$printer -> text($tax);
$printer -> selectPrintMode(Printer::MODE_DOUBLE_WIDTH);
$printer -> text($total);
$printer -> selectPrintMode();


/* Footer */
$printer -> feed(2);
$printer -> setJustification(Printer::JUSTIFY_CENTER);
$printer -> text("Gracias por Preferir Nuestro Restobar.\n");
$printer -> text("Ciudad, Region o Provincia.\n");
$printer -> feed(2);

/* Cut the receipt and open the cash drawer */
$printer -> cut();
$printer -> pulse();
$printer -> close();

class item
{
private $name;
private $price;
private $dollarSign;
public function __construct($name = '', $price = '', $dollarSign = false)
{
    $this -> name = $name;
    $this -> price = $price;
    $this -> dollarSign = $dollarSign;
}

public function __toString()
{
    $rightCols = 10;
    $leftCols = 32;
    if ($this -> dollarSign) {
        $leftCols = $leftCols / 2 - $rightCols / 2;
    }
    $left = str_pad($this -> name, $leftCols) ;

    $sign = ($this -> dollarSign ? '' : '');
    $right = str_pad($sign . $this -> price, $rightCols, ' ', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    return "$left$right\n";
}
}
```

Como se puede ver, las consultas estan separadas, ya que por algun motivo, no pude realizar una sola consulta y asi evitarme realizar esto. Pero por temas de tiempo en ese momento, me vi forzado a hacer lo que comento.
Estoy usando Windows Print Connector, ya que la impresora de caja la tengo conectada via USB. Si se usa otro tipo de puerto (SERIAL o PARALELO), se debe cambiar el tipo de conector.
Si se usa una impresora conectada a otro PC, se debe usar CURL (verificar que la extension este habilitada en php.ini) y enviar los datos por POST, al menos asi lo hice, ya que al enviarlos por GET, no me funciono.

Obviamente, se debe adaptar a las necesidades de cada quien. Puse las consultas a mi BD de pruebas para que se tenga una idea de como se van formando los diferentes conceptos a imprimir.
Si se usa una impresora epson, lo mas probable es que tengas que modificar los margenes laterales y el tamaño de letra y eso lo haces cambiando o disminuyendo los valores de:

```
$rightCols = 10;
$leftCols = 32;
```

Tambien se deben importar las libreriras necesarias, compartir la impresora y todo lo que se necesita para la impresion POS.